# How to point external domain to a rancher kubernetes deployment

Tags: rancher, rancher-rke

I'm running Rancher on my local PC with a DNS entry for my domain at https://my.domain.org. I can access the Rancher UI from the internet.

I've also deployed the rancher/hello-world:latest, and it's accessible locally.

I'd like to access my hello-world app from the internet at https://my.domain.org/hello.

- I've tried creating "Service Discovery - Ingresses".
- I've also tried "Service Discovery - Services - LoadBalancer".

However, I haven't had any success. Can anyone provide a step-by-step solution? I'm using the latest Rancher UI. Additionally, a comprehensive tutorial that covers this exact scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To expose an endpoint, you need to configure your app/workload to use a service. If you're running this from a home network, I'd recommend using NodePort to expose your workload to a port on the node(s) running in your cluster.

In rancher, you can do this when you deploy your workload (or edit an existing workload) as the options in the UI include a services section. This will create the service on behalf of the user, which sounds like what you're trying to do manually re: ingress/LoadBalancer.

Again if you're on a home network, you may have additional steps like forwarding the nodeport range, which by default is 30000-32767.